# Combine Remote Config Values into a new Value

Tags: firebase-remote-config

I am currently working on a project that uses Firebase Remote Config for feature flags. What I am wanting to try and do is create a new flag that combines multiple other values in the config. For instance:

Feature 1: True
Feature 2: True
Feature 3: False

Feature 4 = Feature 1 || Feature 2 || Feature 3 = True

Is this possible in Remote Config?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to create multiple conditional values with the same value in the fourth parameter.

Like:

```
Parameter Feature 4:
       default_value: FALSE
       if condition_value_1: TRUE
       if condition_value_2: TRUE
       if condition_value_3: TRUE
```